# How to fix freezing Active Indicator when pulling to refresh in the Table View

Tags: ios, swift

Every time when I use pull to refresh, the Active Indicator and the application itself freeze for a moment. I found which method is causing this problem - getTracks(), if I remove it then everything works well (except that the table is not updated), but I can't figure out what's the matter, I've tried many options, but no result. Can anyone help me?
My code:

```
class LibraryViewController: UIViewController {
   private let fetchManager = FetchManager()
   private var tracks: [TrackModelProtocol] = []
   ...
   private let refreshControl: UIRefreshControl = {
        let refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()
        refreshControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(refreshTableView), for: .valueChanged)
        return refreshControl
    }()
   ...
   override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        ...
        getTracks()
        setupTableView()
        tableView.refreshControl = refreshControl
    }
   ...
   private func getTracks() {
        guard let tracks = fetchManager.setupTrackModels() else { return }
        self.tracks = tracks
    }
    
   //pull to refresh
   @objc private func refreshTableView(sender: UIRefreshControl) {
        getTracks()
        tableView.reloadData()
        sender.endRefreshing()
   }
   ...
}
...
class FetchManager {
   var content: [URL] = []
    
    private var currentDirectory : URL?
    private var playerQueue: [AVPlayerItem] = []
    
    private let audioPlayer = AudioPlayer()
    
    private func fetchDataFromDeviceMemory() -> [URL]? {
        var content: [URL] = []
        
        if currentDirectory == nil {
            currentDirectory = try! FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: false)
        }
        do {
            let allURLs = try FileManager.default.contentsOfDirectory(at: currentDirectory!, includingPropertiesForKeys: nil, options: [.skipsHiddenFiles, .skipsPackageDescendants])
            content = allURLs.filter{ $0.pathExtension == "mp3" || $0.pathExtension == "aac" || $0.pathExtension == "wav" }
        } catch {
            content = []
        }
    
        return content
    }
    
    func setupTrackModels() -> [TrackModelProtocol]? {
        guard let content = fetchDataFromDeviceMemory() else { return [] }
        self.content = content
        playerQueue = audioPlayer.createPlayerQueue(from: content)
        var tracks: [TrackModelProtocol] = []
        
        for index in 0..<playerQueue.count {
            
            var artwork: UIImage?
            
            let playerItem = playerQueue[index]
            let metadataList = playerItem.asset.metadata
            
            for item in metadataList {
                guard let key = item.commonKey?.rawValue, let value = item.value else{
                    continue
                }
                
                switch key {
                case "artwork" where value is Data:
                    artwork = UIImage(data: value as! Data)
                default:
                    continue
                }
            }
            
            let track = TrackFromDeviceMemory(
                fileName: content[index].lastPathComponent,
                duration: playerQueue[index].asset.duration.seconds,
                artwork: artwork,
                url: content[index].absoluteURL)
            
            tracks.append(track)
        }
        
        return tracks
    }
}



 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        
        if editingStyle == .delete {
            
            if isSearchActive {
                let deletedTrackURL = filteredTracks[indexPath.row].url
                print(deletedTrackURL)
                do {
                    try FileManager.default.removeItem(at: deletedTrackURL)
                } catch {
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                }
                
                getTracks()
                searchController.isActive = false
//                tableView.reloadData()
                tableView.delegate?.tableView!(tableView, didSelectRowAt: IndexPath(row: 0, section: indexPath.section))
                
                
            } else {
                let deletedTrackURL = tracks[indexPath.row].url
                print(deletedTrackURL)
                do {
                    try FileManager.default.removeItem(at: deletedTrackURL)
                } catch {
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                }
                
                getTracks()
                tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
//                tableView.reloadData()
```

Comment: IMO it would be better to move `tableView.reloadData()` and  `sender.endRefreshing()` in  `getTracks()` method after getting response from the API. try that and see if that works.

Comment: I did as you say, moved tableView.reloadData() and tableView.refreshControl.endRefreshing() to the getTracks() func, but it doesn't help

Comment: It seems to me that the problem is in getting tracks from the device memory

Comment: Have you try to use `DispatchQueue.main`?

Comment: What exactly should I put in the main queue?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of returning an array with `setupTrackModels`, have you tried using a completion handler and perform the fetch on a global queue? Performing the fetch on the main queue itself might be the reason for freeze.

```
func setupTrackModels(completion: (_ models: [TrackModelProtocol])->Void) {
    DispatchQueue.global().async {
        guard let content = fetchDataFromDeviceMemory() else {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                completion([])
                return
            }
        }
        self.content = content
        playerQueue = audioPlayer.createPlayerQueue(from: content)
        var tracks: [TrackModelProtocol] = []
        
        for index in 0..<playerQueue.count {
            
            var artwork: UIImage?
            
            let playerItem = playerQueue[index]
            let metadataList = playerItem.asset.metadata
            
            for item in metadataList {
                guard let key = item.commonKey?.rawValue, let value = item.value else{
                    continue
                }
                
                switch key {
                case "artwork" where value is Data:
                    artwork = UIImage(data: value as! Data)
                default:
                    continue
                }
            }
            
            let track = TrackFromDeviceMemory(
                fileName: content[index].lastPathComponent,
                duration: playerQueue[index].asset.duration.seconds,
                artwork: artwork,
                url: content[index].absoluteURL)
            
            tracks.append(track)
        }
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            completion(tracks)
        }
    }
}
```

At the call site:

```
        fetchManager.setupTrackModels { tracks in
            refreshControl.endRefreshing()
            self.tracks = tracks
            tableView.reloadData()
        }
```

Comment: It works, but now when I delete the row the application crashes. In the func ...commit editingStyle... I use ...tableView.delegate?.tableView!(tableView, didSelectRowAt... 
And asyncAfter does not help

Comment: I added to the main question

Comment: Is it crashing on `getTracks()` or `tableView.delegate?.tableView!(tableView, didSelectRowAt`? whats the error printed in console?

Comment: Error: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0. The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (29) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (29), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (0 inserted, 1 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out)

Comment: It crashes when data reloads

Comment: It could be due to `tableView.reloadData()` getting called inside `getTracks()` right after  `tableView.deleteRow`. Please try commenting out  `tableView.deleteRows`.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I comment it and app doesn't crash. How can I fix it?

Comment: Didn't that change fix the issue? Now the row is getting deleted properly right? Is there anything wrong with it?

Comment: Sorry, it works. I forget what I use flag needsTiReloadData in getTracks() func. Thank you very much

Comment: But the method tableView.delegate?.tableView!(tableView, didSelectRowAt... stopped working

Comment: Previously, when I deleted a line, the next track started playing.

Comment: Do you have `tableView.delegate?.tableView!(tableView, didSelectRowAt` added in `isSearchActive` and else case?

Comment: no, it added only in case where isSearchActive == true

Comment: I went the other way, rolled my code back as it was. And in @objc private func refreshTableView (sender: UIRefreshControl) put getTracks () on the global queue. Everything seems to be working.